# BLDC motor's frequency

Tags: pwm, brushless-dc-motor

I have a 3-phase motor. I want to find out the frequency of the motor so that I can supply the required PWM frequency for the motor.

My motor specification:

- 360 Watts (36v and 10A) rated max
- 30 poles
- 750rpm
- line-to-line resistance = 0.7ohm, line-to-neutral resistance = 0.35ohm

PWM Frequency = 1/2*pi*t where t = L/R

Is the above formula right for frequency calculation?

Comment: Do you mean to use PWM to control commutation open-loop? That won't work once the motor is loaded, because the mechanical load slows the rotor and commutation timing will need to adjust. Either use hall-effect sensors or back-emf sensing to determine when to switch phases. PWM is useful for reducing the effective voltage (unloaded speed RPM) on the active phase, but PWM is not useful for determining when to switch phases.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be misunderstanding the underlying principle of BLDC commutation. The equation t = L/R I believe is used to determine the minimum PWM frequency necessary, but in practice you will want your PWM frequency to be higher than this to increase power efficiency. Often a frequency that is above audible (>20kHz) is used so that you can't hear an annoying whine from the coils, but this varies depending on the control technique used and the hardware it is being implemented on.

If you're building your own BLDC solution, I recommend starting with learning how trapezoidal control works. There are many great documents online from major companies such as TI, NXP, etc. that describe it.

Comment: Ok I got it, that is if I calculate the pwm frequency (t=L/R) which is the minimum frequency of that bldc motor. So we have to increase that min frequency to attain noiseless performance.

Comment: to clarify, it won't be 'noiseless' if it's higher than L/R. Getting it in a higher frequency range will just mitigate the voice coil effect of the motor, it won't have any bearing on the noise that is produced when the motor spins.